# what is the best practice when starting a process or a systemd service from python

Tags: python, service, subprocess, child-process, ngrok

I'm using `ngrok` to expose my application to the internet, now I'm trying to make the process of starting `ngrok` process automated with my application so  I created this (minimal) code:

*main.py*

```py
def is_ngrok_running():
  try:
    if requests.get("http://localhost:4040/"):
      return True
  except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError :
    return False

def start_ngrok(): 
  subprocess.Popen(["ngrok", "http", "8020", "--log=stdout" ],
                   stderr= subprocess.DEVNULL,
                   stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                   )

def start_server(): 
  if not is_ngrok_running(): 
    start_ngrok()
  
  application.start()
```

and this works fine, but sometimes the application restarts or stops due to errors when testing, this will also restart the `ngrok` process, hence the public domain to access the application changes and I have to change it each time in the client code.

Now I want to achieve following goals:

1. if the `ngrok` process is not running, start it.
2. when the application exits don't kill the the `ngrok` child process.

I tried using a `systemd` service but this didn't work out for me.